# What is meant by <app-setting> in dot net project web.config file.?

Tags: asp.net

What is meant by  in dot net project web.config file.?

We are using the app-setting in the web.config file for mapping the database. In this  How we can use the  and their attributes.?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a .NET application there is a configuration file named web.config in the site that contains information like settings and connection strings.

This file is a simple XML file and contains information such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="May 5, 2014"/>
    <add key="Setting2" value="May 6, 2014"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You can use the settings in the .NET application by reference the configuration manager.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx